# Issue trying to create my first oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that on INSERT or UPDATE of a record where the TESTGROUP == 'HSSAG' that a duplicate of that record would be created for the TESTGROUP 'HSBEJ' ..... and when a record for HSSAG was updated, the associated HSBEJ record would then be updated.

```
create or replace TRIGGER VAL_TESTTYPE_CLONING 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF TESTGROUP ON CLONING_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (new.TESTGROUP = 'HSSAG') 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CLONING_TABLE (TESTCOL, TESTGROUP) VALUES(:new.TESTCOL, 'HSBEJ');
END;
```

This is the error i get when i try to insert

```
INSERT INTO "CLMSDBA"."CLONING_TABLE" (TESTCOL, TESTGROUP) VALUES ('3', 'HSSAG')
ORA-04091: table CLMSDBA.CLONING_TABLE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "CLMSDBA.VAL_TESTTYPE_CLONING", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CLMSDBA.VAL_TESTTYPE_CLONING'
ORA-06512: at line 1


One error saving changes to table "CLMSDBA"."CLONING_TABLE":
Row 3: ORA-04091: table CLMSDBA.CLONING_TABLE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "CLMSDBA.VAL_TESTTYPE_CLONING", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CLMSDBA.VAL_TESTTYPE_CLONING'
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Does table VAL_TESTTYPE have a column called TESTCOL? (and not for example "TestCol"?)

Comment: `:new.TESTCOL` => `:new.TESTGROUP`, assuming the 2 tables have same cols.

Comment: :new, not new in when

Comment: Sorry, I found some mistakes in the table and column name just after I posted that I corrected, then got another error that makes no sense to me.

Comment: you cannot insert into same table inside triiger, if you want substitute some value just use :new.col_name = ...

Comment: Are you are saying that I can't use a trigger to INSERT a record into the same table?

Comment: Yes, if you want just replace column value use this: create or replace TRIGGER VAL_TESTTYPE_CLONING 
before DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF TESTGROUP ON CLONING_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (new.TESTGROUP = 'HSSAG') 
BEGIN
  :new.testgroup := 'HSBEJ';
END;
/

Comment: I don't want to replace the column value ...... when a record value for HSSAG is created then a duplicate for HSBEJ needs to be added. I can always create a temp table that triggers back on the sender to accomplish what I need if it can't be done in a single table and trigger.

Comment: May be this hepls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167200/insert-trigger-for-inserting-record-in-same-table

Comment: I tried using a "temp" table to receive the new values, then have a trigger on the "temp" table insert them into the source table, but that caused a mutation error as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a very good workaround for mutating trigger issues. Hope this
>   helps.

[Mutating trigger workaround](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions)